# How to add a watermark to gifs and maximum compression it by imagemagick?

Tags: compression, imagemagick

Now the method I use is:

```
convert input.gif -coalesce -gravity SouthWest -geometry + 0 + 0 null: watermark.png -layers composite -layers optimize output.gif
```

But it does not compress gifs, I use Ulead gif add a watermark to the same picture was found after export gifs size even smaller than the original,How to add a watermark to gifs and maximum compression it by imagemagick?

Comment: Your command looks most odd to me - specifically the `-coalesce`, the `+0 +0` geometry, the `null:` and the `-layers` commands! Can you provide the input image, the watermark and the expected output image please so I can see what you are trying to do?